# Summernote Code is over writing Inline CSS Style tag to [Removed]

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3, summernote

I am trying to edit text in summernote then on submit I send the form data to codeignator via ajax 
at ajax level the code looks fine but when it reaches to server the inline  css tag (style="anything:anything"); changed to  ([removed]="anything:anything");

```
 var form = $('#' + form_id);
form.find('.summernotes').each(function () {
    var now = $(this);
    var str = now.code();
    now.closest('div').find('.val').val(str);
});
var formdata = false;
if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
}
formdata.append('globalText', '<table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>ikonami 11<br></td><td style="text-align: right;">ikonami 12<br></td></tr><tr><td>ikonami 23<br></td><td style="text-align: right;">ikonami 24<br></td></tr></tbody></table>');
$.ajax({
url: form.attr('action'), // form action url
        type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
        dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
        data: formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
        var buttonp = $('.enterer');
                buttonp.addClass('disabled');
                buttonp.html(working);
        },
        success: function () {
        return;
                error: function (e) {
                console.log(e)
                }
        });
```